# From a few Excel files to PowerPoint

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I'm totally new in VBA programming. However I have to (and want) create macro in Excel file to automatically creating PowerPoint presentation.

I hope that someone will be able to help me or have a similar problem.
Namely - I have 6 columns in the Excel file:

```
1 - slide number
2 - file access path
3 - file name
4 - sheet name
5 - slide range
6 - slide title
```

I would like the macro to automatically enter a given file -> sheet -> take the slide's range, copy and paste it as a picture for the presentation and give it the appropriate title and go through the loop to the next line and do the same.

Is anyone able to help me? Below is the code that I managed to write, however, I do not know how to refer to the sheet and the range of the slide from the given cell.

[image: Example on the screen]

```
Option Explicit

Sub ExcelRangeToPowerPoint()
     Dim rng As Range
     Dim PowerPointApp As Object
     Dim myPresentation As Object
     Dim mySlide As Object
     Dim myShape As Object
     Dim adr1 As String
     Dim shta As Worksheet
     Dim wrk As String

     Application.DisplayAlerts = False

     wrk = ThisWorkbook.Name ' nname
     adr1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")

    'Copy Range from Excel
    ' Set rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A1:C12")

    'Create an Instance of PowerPoint
      On Error Resume Next

    'Is PowerPoint already opened?
      Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

    'Clear the error between errors
      Err.Clear

    'If PowerPoint is not already open then open PowerPoint
      If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

    'Handle if the PowerPoint Application is not found
      If Err.Number = 429 Then
        MsgBox "PowerPoint could not be found, aborting."
        Exit Sub
      End If

     On Error GoTo 0

    'Optimize Code
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False

     'Create a New Presentation
      Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add

      ThisWorkbook.Activate
      Range("A2").Select
     'DO While
      Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
          Workbooks.Open Filename:=(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) & "\" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)), UpdateLinks:=0, ReadOnly:=True ' to be sure read-only open
          ' Worksheet Open from D2
          'Copy Range from E2

          'Add a slide to the Presentation
          Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(1, 11) '11 = ppLayoutTitleOnly
          'Paste to PowerPoint and position
          mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2  '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile + title from F2
          Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)

          ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False  ' close file and don't save
          ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1").Select
      Loop

      MsgBox ("Ready")
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
      Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: hope this help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=We8ZOhqxUtY

Comment: it would be helpful, but all my data source from which I want to create some slides are in a few excel files. 
And that's my problem, because I do not know how to refer to sheets and ranges in other files. But thank you for a quick answer :)

Comment: lets say you are in sheet 2 and if you want to refer from sheet 1 use =sheet1!A1    hope it helps. Use ! to refer to other sheet

Comment: Ok, but how can i refer to some sheet and some range from another workbook (Warning! - name of this sheet and range is in column D and E) - You can look on the screen which I added.

Comment: for the range are you intending to sum the value?? or something else(explain a little more)? if you are, try =sheet1!SUM(B2:N15)

Comment: I am going to enter the file from the cell C2 and then to the cell sheet D2 - mark the cell area E2 (B2: N15) and copy it and paste it as an image in slide No. 1 - and You know it has to be loop

Comment: sorry unable to help but glad that you found an answer :>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always refer to some sheet or Workbook creating first variables type Workbook or Worksheets.

If you want to refer a variable to a worksheet/workbook, is pretty easy. Is just a set. Something like:

```
Dim wb as Workbook
Set wb = ThisWorkbook
```

Now **wb** will be referenced to ThisWorkbook Object. With Worksheets is the same. You refer exactly the same way:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
```

Now **ws** is referenced to activesheet and you can handle it from ws.

I hope this answered some of your doubts. About your code, the loop part should be something like this:

```
Dim MyWb As Workbook 'variable for workbook
Dim MyWs As Worksheet 'variable for worksheet

ThisWorkbook.Activate
Range("A2").Select
'DO While
Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
    ThisWorkook.Activate
    Set MyWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) & "\" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)), UpdateLinks:=0, ReadOnly:=True) ' to be sure read-only open
    ' Worksheet Open from D2

    Set MyWs = MyWb.Worksheets(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value) 'now MyWs is referenced to the worksheet in column D

    'Copy Range from E2
    MyWs.Activate
    MyWs.Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value).Copy 'we copy the range shown in column E


    'Add a slide to the Presentation
    Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(1, 11) '11 = ppLayoutTitleOnly
    'Paste to PowerPoint and position
    mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2  '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile + title from F2
    Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)

    'after pasting, we go back to active workbook
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    MyWb.Activate

    MyWb.Close SaveChanges:=False  ' close file and don't save
    Set MyWs = Nothing
    Set MyWb = Nothing
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 'we go 1 row down
Loop
```

I hope you can test it and tell me if it helped you to make thing clear :)

Comment: Hello,
Really thanks for answer. I tried to run Your code, but
I got message that " Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed.
In this line:
         MyWs.Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value).Copy 'we copy the range shown in column E

So I think I should also Dim for Range something like You did for MyWb and MyWs, but frankly speaking I don;t know how to do this..

Comment: In that line you said, what is the value of `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value` ? Also, did it work at least once? Or it instantly failed? Because I runned something similar right now in my pc and it worked.

Comment: Also, make sure all values in column E are typed right. For example, E3 you have_ "AB11:AK:26"_ and it should be **"AB11:AK26"**. Note the difference, your value got 2 colons and that causes error, right way to type is just 1 colon.

Comment: I had to add one line (ThisWorkbook.Activate) - 
         'Copy Range from E2
    
          ThisWorkbook.Activate
           MyWs.Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value).Copy


and You are firght I had bugs, but i corrected it and still something is wrong. 2 slides I have but after this I have message from VBA: Subscript out of range for this line:

 Set MyWs = MyWb.Worksheets(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value) 'now MyWs is referenced to the worksheet in column D

Answer (score 0):

Really Thanks for answer
I had to use "ThisWorkbook.Activate" in a few places.
And now this macro work almost perfect.. it means that the order of creating slides is reversed : 1 is the last and the last is 1..
What is more I'd like to also create Title of each slide from Excel file column F.

Below my VBA code:

```
Sub VBA_PowerPoint()

Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Dim myPresentation As Object
Dim mySlide As Object
Dim myShape As Object
Dim MyWb As Workbook 'variable for workbook
Dim MyWs As Worksheet 'variable for worksheet
Dim MyRg As Excel.Range ' variable for Range

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ThisWorkbook.Activate
Range("A2").Select

'Create an Instance of PowerPoint
  On Error Resume Next

'Is PowerPoint already opened?
  Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

'Clear the error between errors
  Err.Clear

'If PowerPoint is not already open then open PowerPoint
  If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

 'Handle if the PowerPoint Application is not found
  If Err.Number = 429 Then
    MsgBox "PowerPoint could not be found, aborting."
    Exit Sub
  End If

  On Error GoTo 0

 'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 'Create a New Presentation
  Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add


 'Do While
 ThisWorkbook.Activate

Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
 ThisWorkbook.Activate
 Set MyWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) & "\" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)), UpdateLinks:=0, ReadOnly:=True) ' to be sure read-only open
 ' Worksheet Open from D2
 ThisWorkbook.Activate
 Set MyWs = MyWb.Worksheets(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value) 'now MyWs is referenced to the worksheet in column D

 'Copy Range from E2
' Set MyRg = MyWs.Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value) 'now MyWs is referenced to the worksheet in column E

' MyWs.Range(MyRg).Copy 'we copy the range shown in column E
 ThisWorkbook.Activate
 MyWs.Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value).Copy


 'Add a slide to the Presentation
 Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(1, 11) '11 = ppLayoutTitleOnly
 'Paste to PowerPoint and position
 mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2  '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile + title from F2
 Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)

 'after pasting, we go back to active workbook
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  MyWb.Activate

  MyWb.Close SaveChanges:=False  ' close file and don't save
  Set MyWs = Nothing
  Set MyWb = Nothing
  ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select 'we go 1 row down
Loop


Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Glad to help, but if this is a new request, you should open a new question :)

Also, about "thisworkbook.Activate" you are right. I used object "Activecell" but to make sure this object works, you have to activate the workbook as you did. I totally forgot, but if you got what you want, I'm glad for it.

Comment: But to use a reference to title in column F, should be something like `MyWs.Range(ActiveCell.Offset(0, 5).Value).Copy` 5 columns to the right of column A means column F

Comment: I'm going to create seperate question about it. Yes thank You so much for Your help.
btw with the title something still is not ok.